# for every restaurants there are offers i need offer information to be displayed.please help me how can i write that in handle response

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
{"status":"1","result":"Success","restaurants":[{"establishment_id":"65","name":"Cafe loop","distance":"0.92078813710168","category_id":"[\"1\"]","address":"Rd Number 4, Zahara Nagar, Banjara Hills, Hyderabad, Telangana 500034, India","location":"","latitude":"17.44492","longitude":"78.38607","loc_id":"ChIJ4zeZ21-RyzsR-WLkgTksNNQ","contact_number":"9052681285","website":"","logo":"1501242307-71.jpg","gst_value":"15","order_type":"1","delivery_time":"35","open_time":"12","close_time":"24","min_order_value":"100","rating":"3","cuisines":"Coffee, Sandwiches","restauant_value":null,"restauant_availability":0,"terminate_status":"1","favourite":0,"offer":[]},{"establishment_id":"61","name":"100 degrees","distance":"1.8377029731045318","category_id":"0","address":"KKR Square, Kavuri Hills, Opposite HDFC Bank, Madhapur, Chennai","location":"","latitude":"17.452025","longitude":"78.374268","loc_id":"ChIJ6URfYESRyzsR9WpUYsApREg","contact_number":"040 33165636","website":"","logo":"15063437104400.jpg","gst_value":"18","order_type":"1","delivery_time":"25","open_time":"12","close_time":"24","min_order_value":"2000","rating":"3.5","cuisines":"Biryani, Chines, Noodles","restauant_value":null,"restauant_availability":0,"terminate_status":"1","favourite":0,"offer":[{"offer_id":"3","name":"10 % OFF","image":"1497245535-22.png","offer_value":"5","establishment_id":"82"}]},{"establishment_id":"62","name":"1857","distance":"0.5418675854412125","category_id":"[\"3\"]","address":"Madhura Plaza, Opposite Fortune Towers, Hitech City Road, Madhapur, Hyderabad","location":"","latitude":"17.441495","longitude":"78.39056","loc_id":"ChIJo9nbIlyRyzsRl35mjhaKsCw","contact_number":"040 60124111","website":"","logo":"1501242359-69.jpg","gst_value":"18","order_type":"1","delivery_time":"30","open_time":"15","close_time":"24","min_order_value":"500","rating":"2","cuisines":"Biryani, Chines Noodles,Japanese Food","restauant_value":null,"restauant_availability":0,"terminate_status":"1","favourite":0,"offer":[{"offer_id":"2","name":"25 % OFF","image":"1459146271-55.jpg","offer_value":"2","establishment_id":"83"}]},{"establishment_id":"63","name":"70MM","distance":"1.0438443764324992","category_id":"[\"8\"]","address":"KKR Square, Kavuri Hills, Opposite HDFC Bank, Madhapur, Hyderabad","location":"","latitude":"17.451487","longitude":"78.394345","loc_id":"ChIJtxUnC2aRyzsRnHUoQd8I9jc","contact_number":"9014762266","website":"","logo":"1501242347-73.jpg","gst_value":"18","order_type":"1","delivery_time":"45","open_time":"11","close_time":"17","min_order_value":"600","rating":"5","cuisines":"Chinese, Thai, Indian","restauant_value":null,"restauant_availability":0,"terminate_status":"1","favourite":0,"offer":[{"offer_id":"3","name":"10 % OFF","image":"1497245535-22.png","offer_value":"5","establishment_id":"82"}]},{"establishment_id":"64","name":"Chowpatti","distance":"0.6183529824343034","category_id":"[\"3\"]","address":"8-2-603\/B\/34\/2, Road Number 10, Singada Kunta, Banjara Hills, Hyderabad, Telangana 500034, India","location":"","latitude":"17.443138","longitude":"78.39058","loc_id":"ChIJw3oD0l2RyzsRczw121-Fu_c","contact_number":"9010540019","website":"","logo":"1501242319-16.jpg","gst_value":"18","order_type":"1","delivery_time":"40","open_time":"10","close_time":"13","min_order_value":"1500","rating":"4.2","cuisines":"Chapathi","restauant_value":null,"restauant_availability":0,"terminate_status":"1","favourite":0,"offer":[{"offer_id":"2","name":"25 % OFF","image":"1459146271-55.jpg","offer_value":"2","establishment_id":"83"}]},{"establishment_id":"66","name":"Ohri's Daba","distance":"1.3956541855844804","category_id":"[\"3\"]","address":"KKR Square, Kavuri Hills, Opposite HDFC Bank, Madhapur, Hyderabad","location":"","latitude":"17.45034","longitude":"78.381463","loc_id":"ChIJ1b_L7d2TyzsRapyQ8Y9_7RA","contact_number":"9100700733","website":"","logo":"1501242293-42.jpg","gst_value":"18","order_type":"1","delivery_time":"45","open_time":"12","close_time":"23","min_order_value":"100","rating":"4","cuisines":"Starters","restauant_value":null,"restauant_availability":0,"terminate_status":"1","favourite":0,"offer":[{"offer_id":"2","name":"25 % OFF","image":"1459146271-55.jpg","offer_value":"2","establishment_id":"83"}]},{"establishment_id":"87","name":"Paradise Biryani ","distance":"1.4052510235236058","category_id":"0","address":"Road No 45, Jubliee Hills, Checkpost, Hyderabad, 500033","location":"8-2-293\/82\/B\/9, Rd Number 1, Park View Enclave, Jubilee Hills, Hyderabad, Telangana 500033, India","latitude":"17.42669011529984","longitude":"78.41559693217278","loc_id":"ChIJD3toaDKRyzsRBWG7Am4UgaE","contact_number":"9908619977","website":"","logo":"1498033283-80.jpg","gst_value":"18","order_type":"1","delivery_time":"30","open_time":"12","close_time":"24","min_order_value":"600","rating":null,"cuisines":"Indian, Chinese, BBQ","restauant_value":null,"restauant_availability":0,"terminate_status":"1","favourite":0,"offer":[]}],"banners":[{"banner_id":"2","name":"test1","restaurant_id":"62","image":"1501582460-15.png"},{"banner_id":"3","name":"mealshack banner","restaurant_id":"0","image":"1501582405-2.png"}],"restaurant_distance":"2","profileImage":"1502953351-94.jpg","cod_amount":"1000"}
```

Comment: offerinformation means ..?

Comment: for every restaurant there is offer.i need to display that information

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Parsing JSON, there are plenty of question about that. What did you try? What's your code?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to parse data. `offerDetails` is your required array which contains offer details for particular restaurant.

```
let dataDic = ["status":"1","result":"Success","restaurants":[["establishment_id":"65","name":"Cafe loop","distance":"0.92078813710168","category_id":"[\"1\"]","address":"Rd Number 4, Zahara Nagar, Banjara Hills, Hyderabad, Telangana 500034, India","location":"","latitude":"17.44492","longitude":"78.38607","loc_id":"ChIJ4zeZ21-RyzsR-WLkgTksNNQ","contact_number":"9052681285","website":"","logo":"1501242307-71.jpg","gst_value":"15","order_type":"1","delivery_time":"35","open_time":"12","close_time":"24","min_order_value":"100","rating":"3","cuisines":"Coffee, Sandwiches","restauant_value":"","restauant_availability":0,"terminate_status":"1","favourite":0,"offer":[]],["establishment_id":"61","name":"100 degrees","distance":"1.8377029731045318","category_id":"0","address":"KKR Square, Kavuri Hills, Opposite HDFC Bank, Madhapur, Chennai","location":"","latitude":"17.452025","longitude":"78.374268","loc_id":"ChIJ6URfYESRyzsR9WpUYsApREg","contact_number":"040 33165636","website":"","logo":"15063437104400.jpg","gst_value":"18","order_type":"1","delivery_time":"25","open_time":"12","close_time":"24","min_order_value":"2000","rating":"3.5","cuisines":"Biryani, Chines, Noodles","restauant_value":"","restauant_availability":0,"terminate_status":"1","favourite":0,"offer":[["offer_id":"3","name":"10 % OFF","image":"1497245535-22.png","offer_value":"5","establishment_id":"82"]]]]]

    let arrayRest = dataDic.objectForKey("restaurants") as? NSArray
    if arrayRest != nil
    {
        for element in arrayRest
        {
            let restDic = element as? NSDictionary
            if restDic != nil
            {
                let offerDetails = restDic.objectForKey("offer") as? NSArray
                print(offerDetails)
            }
        }
    }
```